# Print each line if not equal to previous line

Tags: c, function

I need to write a function `void process_file(FILE* f)` that reads all input from the given file one line at the time while keeping two consecutive lines in memory and prints each line to the standard output if it is not equal to the previously read line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MY_MAX_LINE 999

void process_file(FILE* f)
{
  char firstLine[MY_MAX_LINE + 1];
  char secondLine[MY_MAX_LINE + 1]; 

  while (1)
  {
    if (!fgets(firstLine, sizeof(firstLine), f))
      break;

    puts(firstLine);

    if (!fgets(secondLine, sizeof(secondLine), f))
      break;

    if (strncmp(firstLine, secondLine, sizeof(firstLine)))
      puts(secondLine);
  }

  if (!feof(f))
    perror("Problem reading from file"), exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  FILE *f = fopen("text.txt", "r");

  if (!f)
    perror("text.txt"), exit(1);

  process_file(f);
  fclose(f);

  return 0;
}
```

I want to know if I'm doing this correctly and if this is what the question is asking.

Thanks!

Comment: Your code won't work if the user types in a line and then the same line twice. It will only work if the first and second lines are the same, or the third and fourth, fifth and sixth, and so on.

Comment: Nope, not correct. For example, if the input is `ABBC`, the output should be `ABC`, but your code will output `ABBC` because it only compares `A` to `B` and the second `B` to `C`.

Comment: Please see [ask]. What do you get when you run the program?

Comment: I cannot be bothered to write a full answer (I have been programming all day), but here's just a tip to send you down the right path: `char lastLine[... whatever...]; char currentLine[...]; while(fgets(... currentLine ...)){ if(lastLine is different from currentLine){ print(currentLine); copy(currentLine to lastLine); }/*end if*/ }` Terrible formatting because this is a comment, but beautify (properly format) that pseudocode and it should get you started towards a solution.

Comment: `if (strncmp(firstLine, secondLine, sizeof(firstLine)))` should be `if (strncmp(firstLine, secondLine, strlen(firstLine)))`

Comment: ^^that didn't make a difference, and I'm still stuck at what @kichik said I can't get it so if the second and third are the same.

Comment: You need to think of a new method of doing this. Think of how you would solve this yourself without code and try implementing that.

Comment: @kichik  Yeah, I know the idea, like going through each line and then if the current line, is equal to the previous like, print current line, if not then print current and previous line, implementing it is the problem, since I'm new to c

Comment: But that's not what you have done. You are reading two lines and the comparing them. If they are the same, you go back to read two more lines. That's why the second and third line are never compared. You need to find a way to compare each line to the previous one. After you've compared it, the current line becomes the previous line for the next comparison.

Comment: `if (!feof(f))` need not be there. Use `while(fgets(secondLine, sizeof secondLine, f) != NULL) {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it. First start with an array of 2 lines, so that you can use indexes to select the current and previous lines.

```
char line[2][MAXL];
```

Then declare two indexes. The first index, `ping`, is the index of the current line. The other index, `pong`, is the index of the previous line. `pong` is initialized to an invalid index, since the first line in the file has no predecessor.

```
int ping = 0;     // index of the current line
int pong = -1;    // index of the previous line
```

Then you need a `while` loop to read from the file into the current line

```
while ( fgets(line[ping], MAXL, fp) != NULL )
```

Now we must decide: to print, or not to print. There are two conditions under which current line is printed. First, if `pong < 0` then the line is the first line. The first line is always printed. Second, if the line doesn't match the previous line (as determined by `strcmp`), then the line is printed.

```
if ( pong < 0 || strcmp(line[0], line[1]) != 0 )
    printf( "%s", line[ping] );
```

Finally, we need to update the indexes to prepare for the next line. We want one of the indexes to be `0` and the other to be `1`, and they should swap on every pass through the loop. `pong` is the index of the previous line, so we store the index of the current line into `pong`. Then we toggle `ping` from 0 to 1, or vice versa.

```
pong = ping;
ping = 1 - ping;
```